# Is there a way to iterate through type-safe project accessors?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I have a few directories with modules: base, library, feature.
And i need to use modules from each directory in main application module. Something like this:

```
projects.base.myProjects.forEach { dep: DelegatingProjectDependency ->
    implementation(dep)
}
```

The problem is that `BaseProjectDependency` does not have a method for getting all of its dependencies, but only separate methods for each.
I tried following the advice from here https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16784 , but it didn't work for me. Is there a way to do what i want?

gradle version is 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked about it on gradle forums and Vampire help me.
According on his answer, solution is

```
projects.base.dependencyProject.subprojects.forEach {
        implementation(it)
    }
```

Original https://discuss.gradle.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-iterate-through-type-safe-project-accessors/46175